# what is the best tool to compare SQL Server database schemas across different db servers

Tags: sql-server, comparison, database-schema

i have to compare two SQL server databases:

1. The databases are on different db servers (i see a few tools but they assume both databases are on the same db server which falls short of my requirements)
2. I want to compare at the schema level because one database has a number of different schemas in it and I only want to compare one schema.

are there any good tools to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best tool I've come across for doing this is [SQLCompare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) from RedGate. I've never needed to use it to compare at the schema level though.

Comment: I have used it at both schema and data level. Excellent tool. +1

Comment: give it time...[david atkinson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200677/is-there-something-like-activerecordmigration-for-net) is going to be all over this

Answer (score 1):

Sql Examiner will compare database on different servers. I'm not sure about the schema but there is a demoversion

http://www.sqlaccessories.com/Default.aspx

It will also generate scripts to update one database to match the other. I have used the demo version and was impressed. They also have a tool that does the same with your data.

Answer (score 1):

[Red Gate Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) tools offers the features you need. That is, fine grained filtering. Different servers should be standard in any tool IMO.

But they aren't free, however still cheaper than their competitors

Comment: SQL Compare is not cheap. Moreover, it is much more expensive than most competitors

Comment: @SQLDev: examples then please, perhaps so we can compare features too.

Comment: For example, SQL Examiner Suite, mentioned in this topic previously. I'm using this tool, and as far as I know, the tool allows much more than SQL Compare (for example, SQL Examiner works with MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle vs. MSSQL only in SQL Compare). SQL Examiner costs $300 only (compare with ~$700-800 for SQL Compare). You can find more cheaper tools with Google :)

Answer (score 0):

Database tools from Embarcadero seems to work well.

http://www.embarcadero.com/solutions/microsoft-sql-server

They have an option on most of their products for the mode software-on-USB that you can take with you to run without installation.

Answer (score 0):

AdeptSQL Diff http://www.adeptsql.com/